# Xampp Server and Paths

Tags: php, apache, webserver, xampp, html5boilerplate

I'm having hard time with xampp, it realy getting me crazy.
I have few installations of Wordpress with Roots Template, which was loading without any css, js..etc. And the solution was to delete Boilerplates default .htaccess and add:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^assets/css/(.*) /wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/css/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/js/(.*) /wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/js/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^assets/img/(.*) /wp-content/themes/test_template/assets/img/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^plugins/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now i'm facing the same problem but with HTML5 Boilerplate and Twitter-bootstrap, standard html5 file with no complex code. I've tried using:

```
 dirname(__FILE__);
```

And it still can't locate the files. Anybody had the same problem and found the solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try AMPPS. AMPPS is a software stack enabling Apache, Mysql, MongoDB, PHP, Perl, Python and auto-installer on a desktop. This includes everything you need for website development. You can start developing your website from open source web applications or just start writing code yourself. AMPPS lets you code, and test PHP, Perl & Python applications. With AMPPS you can create a website by installing any of the **288 Apps**, customizing it, and then simply publishing it on the internet with integrated FTP client.

AMPPS has a Control Center which controls the Servers like Apache, MySQL, FTP, MongoDB and allows the users to edit the Configuration files of the respective servers and check the Log Files in case of an error... Web site: http://www.ampps.com/

Comment: AMPPS is for win and mac. I'm linux user :) Thanks anyway.